# Android Auto poor voice quality?

Tags: audio, google-maps, google-maps-navigation, android-auto

I am using Android Auto to navigate via Maps, and it works fine. However, the voice quality is much worse than if I use Google Maps and connect my phone via Bluetooth.

I have tried enabling 48KHz Guidance Audio Sample Rate in the developer settings, but it does not make a difference.

Comment: [Known issue](https://support.google.com/androidauto/thread/4171864?hl=en). // See if [this](https://www.autoevolution.com/news/someone-has-found-a-way-to-improve-audio-in-android-auto-142652.html) makes a difference

Comment: Interesting, though that solution seems related to audio streaming. For me, the audio streaming is fine. It is only once the Google Assistant Voice turns on to tell me directions that the audio quality is poor.

Comment: Maybe try with a different voice (male /female) and another language? Just to rule out problems with one voice